# Upload Magento 2 to production server

Tags: magento2, server-setup, upload

I created a store with Magento 2.2.5 in windows and I used as server xampp.
I installed Debian 9 and I want to move my project to it.

1. I copied my project folder to /var/www/html
2. I exported and imported my database
3. I edited base_url in core_config_data
4. I edited app/etc/env.php

Now when I want to access to my store through my web browser I got inaccessible page

[image]

My other php projects works perfectly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple things here.

Step 1: Put a HTML file name index.HTML and put some text like "Working!" and try to browse your the URL to make sure URL is working.

Step 2: If Step 1 works you can remove the index.html. Look into the root folder of Magento to see if you have .htaccess file available. If not then try to copy it from your local dev environment.

Step 3: Look for the server / PHP / Mysql requirement and your new server fulfill all. Same can be found on below URL.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Step 4: Make sure you have correct File permissions. Same can be found on below URL.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html

Step 5: Clear cache, Compile and deploy your static site content.

Step 6: Make sure you keep the environment same as it was on your local server. For example if you have site setup on development then keep the environment set to development on Debian server.